# Vector split/shift elements

Tags: c++, stl, vector, refactoring

I've `std::vector<type> myVector`

lets say content is:

```
el1, el2, el3, splitElement, el4,el5
```

I'm splitting `splitElement` into `split1` and `split2`
I want to have vector:

```
split2, el4, el5, el1, el2, el3, split1
```

Split2 should be begining, split1 end. Other elements order should be like in example. Let's treat vector as chain. I want to insert two elements and shift chain to make split2 first element.
What is the elegant and effective way doing it using stl.

My fast code for now (it's very ugly solution):

```
std::vector<type> before;
std::vector<type> after;
bool afterBool = false;
for(std::vector<type>::iterator it = myVector.begin(); it != myVector.end(); it++)
{
     if(*it == splitElement)
     {
          afterBool = true;
          before.push_back(split1);
          after.push_back(split2);
     }
     else if(afterBool)
          after.push_back(*it);
     else
          before.push_back(*it);
}
myVector.clear();
for(std::vector<type>::iterator it = after.begin(); it != after.end(); it++)
     myVector.push_back(*it);
for(std::vector<type>::iterator it = before.begin(); it != before.end(); it++)
     myVector.push_back(*it);
```

I've added it only cause I don't wanted to leave topic without any code.

How to do it in nice way?

Comment: What does it mean to split an element?

Comment: Create two elements of the same type with some split function. For ex type is integer element is 10 and it can be splited to 5 and 5, when split function is defined to halve element.

Comment: `std::vector<type> after;` `bool after = false;` I will be surprised if this compiles.

Comment: I've right. I've corrected it. This code is written there only to show some current solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example:

```
std::vector<int> myvector = {1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5};
int splitElement = 0;
int split1 = -1;
int split2 = -2;
```

First you find your `splitElement`:

```
auto it = std::find(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), splitElement);
```

Then you rotate the vector at the point you found `splitElement`, using [std::rotate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) algorithm:

```
std::rotate(myvector.begin(), it, myvector.end());
// this yields { 0, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3 }
```

And finally just assign split2 to the beggining and push split1 to the back:

```
myvector[0] = split2;
myvector.push_back(split1);
```

The vector now looks like this: `{-2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, -1}`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to partition your vector. So you can use `std::partition`
To take your example with integers and -1 as the split element.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Splitter
{
    int split;
    Splitter(int sp):split(sp){}
    bool operator()(int i)
    {
    return split < i;
    }
};
int main () {
  vector<int> myvector;
  vector<int>::iterator it, bound;

  // set some values:
  for (int i=1; i<10; ++i) myvector.push_back(i); // 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

  bound = partition (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), Splitter(5));

  myvector.insert(bound, -1);
  cout << "odd members:";
  for (it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
    cout << " " << *it;
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have only added splited elements in splitter position. As I've written vector should be shifted, so split2 should be begining and split1 end.

Comment: @krzych: It is really a very trivial task to add a element to the beginning of a vector. `myvector.insert(myvector.begin(), -1)`

Comment: Look at the question again. Your output is 9 8 7 6 -1 5 4 3 2 1. There should be two elements added (cause it's split) let's say -1 and -2. They should replace 5 (splitter). The output should be -2 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 -1

Answer (score 0):

Since you havent mentioned about the sorting requirement and < operation on the type.
i guess you just want to split the element and make the first split as the last element in a vector and second split as the first element of the vector
I guess the better way to do this is to use a Data structure (Linked list)

- store the elements of the vector in LL
- traverse the list till the split element
- make the second element as head and first element as the tail of LL
- the original tail should be pointing its next to original tal.

aftere these above operation are done.just traverse the ll and store back in a vector.

Comment: Exactly. Second split should be the first element and first the last element. But elements order should be as in my example. Let's treat it as chain. The goal is to insert two elements and shift vector.